# Is there a command in SQL to select 2 or more matches in a list?

Tags: mysql

I'm looking a a few tables for job postings that I am wanting to filter. One of the tables is the "master" table, which is one-to-one has information including the job id, location, and salary. The other table is a "tags" table that is a one-to-many table that has several "tags" (such as education, experience, soft skills, and hard skills) associated with it. Note that there are millions of job id's and therefore even more tags.

"master" table

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦════════╦
║ id   ║  location ║salary  ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬════════╬
║  zy3 ║ CA        ║100,000 ║
║  w1e ║ TX        ║150,000 ║
║  sr2 ║ UT        ║200,000 ║
║  hi9 ║ NY        ║130,000 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩════════╩
```

"tags" table

```
╔══════╦════════╦
║ id   ║  tag   ║ 
╠══════╬════════╬
║  zy3 ║ Python ║
║  zy3 ║ Hadoop ║
║  zy3 ║ master ║
║  w1e ║ Hadoop ║ 
║  w1e ║ BS     ║
║  w1e ║ junior ║ 
║  sr2 ║ Hadoop ║ 
║  sr2 ║ Tech   ║
║  sr2 ║ Stats  ║ 
║  hi9 ║ Java   ║ 
║  hi9 ║ Spark  ║ 
║  hi9 ║ GCP    ║
║  hi9 ║ MS     ║ 
╚══════╩════════╩
```

I am wanting to subset the "Master" table to include only the roles which, for example, includes two or more of the following tags:

Python, Hadoop, Java, Spark

So then the new master table would look like:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦════════╦
║ id   ║  location ║salary  ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬════════╬
║  zy3 ║ CA        ║100,000 ║
║  hi9 ║ NY        ║130,000 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩════════╩
```

I am considering introducing another table which would have a list of different tags I would accept.

To an extent, I've been able to hard-code a solution, but it's really computationally demanding, especially since I am working with millions of rows and sometimes there are many potential tags I would match with (in this case, it was just four tags of interest). Below is the code I have used.

```
select * from master t0 
where (select count(id) from 
((select id from master t1 where t1.id=t0.id and exists (select 1 from tags t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.tag='Python'))
union
(select id from master t1 where t1.id=t0.id and exists (select 1 from tags t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.tag='Hadoop'))
union
(select id from master t1 where t1.id=t0.id and exists (select 1 from tags t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.tag='Java'))
union
(select id from master t1 where t1.id=t0.id and exists (select 1 from tags t2 where t1.id=t2.id and t2.tag='Spark'))) tx) 
>=2;
```

Comment: [How to create table in SO questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/277716/62576)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `UNION`, just use `WHERE tag in (<list of specified tags>)`. Then join that with the `master` table.

```
SELECT m.*
FROM master AS m
JOIN (
    SELECT id
    FROM tags
    WHERE tag in ('python', 'hadoop', 'java', 'spark')
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
) AS t ON m.id = t.id
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you.